# Replacing a string in between known strings over mutiple lines in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm entirely new to powershell and regex stuff, but i need help to do the following:

I need to replace 'VALUE' in a file given that i know the strings before and after it. It runs over multiple lines as well. eg:

```
<knownvalue1>
<knownvalue2>VALUE<knownvalue3>
```

knownvalue 2 and 3 are not unique so i need to include the knownvalue1 as the kind of 'identifier'

Also, To keep in a similar format as what has been previously done it needs to be along the lines of:

```
(gc $filename)-replace "(SEARCHPATTERN)","(REPLACEVAL)" | sc $filename
```

if you can't do it this way, then alternative ways will be okay.

I'm going crazy over this one so any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Is file a valid XML?

Comment: @PetSerAl Yeah, does it make a difference if its xml as opposed to just a text file?

Comment: So if it is a valid XML file you can actually import the file and work with it as an object rather than a collection of strings, which is much cleaner than trying to parse strings.   to start with you'll want to do a get-content and then pipe that to an [Import-Clixml](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849906.aspx), from there you can select the property you are actually trying to change, modify it, and then pipe the object to export-clixml.  If you give it a shot and let us know where you get stuck we can assist.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio Unfortunately, because its something i've gotta do for my job, part of the requirement from them is to make it agnostic to the type of file it is. (eg. it needs to be dealt with as text essentially)
So that's why i believe they want it in the format that i posted above. If its impossible to do it this way, then let me know and thats at least something i can tell them.

Comment: Is every line just one element?  or are there lines with multiple elements like: `<element><knownValue1></knownvalue1></element>`

Comment: @Kage there are multiple lines but not multiple elements, the value that i need to change would essentially be in between the ones you posted as an example. Like: `<knownValue1>
(\n)
<value>VALUETOBECHANGED></value>
(\n)
</knownvalue1>`

Comment: Well its possible, its just dirty and very fault sensitive, lemmie throw something together

Answer (score 0):

Well, When you're importing the file and reading line for line you could split the line up like this:

Bassicly first we split it up on the delimiter `>` After doing so the string will be split up in these parts: `<knownvalue2` and `VALUE<knownvalue3` and `(empty)`

After that it would need to be split again on `>` however now that the string is in parts u need to split it on the parts. which makes it tricky.. and at the same time this is pretty dirty, atleast in my opinion..

```
$value = @()
$value += "<UniqueValue1>"
$value += "<knownvalue2>This Belongs to UniqueValue1<knownvalue3>" 
$value += "</UniqueValue1>"
$value += "<UniqueValue2>"
$value += "<knownvalue2>This Belongs to UniqueValue2<knownvalue3>" 
$value += "</UniqueValue2>"

[int]$count = 0

foreach($line in $value)
{
    if($line.Equals("<UniqueValue1>"))
    {
        $parts = $value[($count + 1)].Split('>');
        "Should be This Belongs to UnqiueValue1<knownvalue3"
        $parts[1]
        ""
        "Second Split"
        $val = $parts[1].Split('<')
        $val[0] + "  #should be This belongs to UniqueValue1"
        $val[1] + "  #should be knownvalue3"
        ""
        "Should be <knownvalue2"
        $parts[0]
    }
    if($line.Equals("<UniqueValue2>"))
    {
        $parts = $value[($count + 1)].Split('>');
        "Should be This belongs to UniqueValue2<knownvalue3"
        $parts[1]
        ""
        "Second Split"
        $val = $parts[1].Split('<')
        $val[0] + "  #should be This Belongs to UniqueValue2"
        $val[1] + "  #should be knownvalue3"
        ""
        "Should be <knownvalue2"
        $parts[0]
    }
    "finished Reading line: $count"
    $count++
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that the '<knownvalue1>' that i mentioned in my original question is used as the 'identifier' as sorts and is unique. knownvalue2 and 3 are known but are not unqiue, so it would edit a tonne of other values doing it the way you've shown.

Comment: In that case u'll make it one giant brain fck, but still possible.. it'll just result in a headache. check my edit.  If its anyhow possible i would suggest importing it as a XML file, it'll make your life soo many times easier then this.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file as one string (`gc` outputs an array which is a very poor choice) and use a simple regex:

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename) -replace `
     '(<knownvalue1>[\s\r\n]*<knownvalue2>)VALUE(<knownvalue3>)',
     '$1(REPLACEVAL)$2'
```

Notes:

- In PS3.0+ you can use `(gc $filename -raw)` instead of `[IO.File]::ReadAllText($filename)`
- In case `<knownvalue1>SKIP SOME OTHER TAGS<knownvalue2>` to catch the SKIP section you can use `<knownvalue1>(?s).*?<knownvalue2>` to match any characters including newline (CR/LF).